# Absolute positioning inside a Floated Relative position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, css-position

The is a boostrap example, as you can see the `span4` is using `pull-right` to float to the right, but the `test` block is position from the beginning of the block so it appear to the `left` instead of `right` in the demo.

What I want is make it position from the real `span4` position, i.e. right instead of left

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
  </head>
  <body>

   <div class="row">
     <div class="span4 pull-right" style='position:relative;'> 
         <div class='test' style='position:fixed;left:0;top:0'>test</div>
     </div>
    <div class="span8"> left </div>
   </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ug2cH/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You realize you are using fixed positioning right now?

`<div class='test' style='position:fixed;left:0;top:0'>test</div>`

Should become

`<div class='test' style='position:absolute;left:0;top:0'>test</div>`

**Updated demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ug2cH/2/